# Python - Qplaintextedit in relation to the Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I don´t know how to search for, so I will ask here.

What I wanna do is, to create a Qplaintextedit within a Window.

Now I execute my programm and resize it as I want, but my qplaintextedit
isn´t changing his size.
There is any function or something I can do, to set them in relation?

Greetings

Edit:
My Code if it helps:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(799, 592)
    MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.desk = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.desk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 781, 551))
    self.desk.setObjectName("desk")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 799, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menuDatei = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuDatei.setObjectName("menuDatei")
    self.menuHilfe = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuHilfe.setObjectName("menuHilfe")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.openFile = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.openFile.setObjectName("openFile")
    self.actionSpeichern = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionSpeichern.setObjectName("actionSpeichern")
    self.actionSpeichern_als = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionSpeichern_als.setObjectName("actionSpeichern_als")
    self.saveFile = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.saveFile.setObjectName("saveFile")
    self.saveFileAs = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.saveFileAs.setObjectName("saveFileAs")
    self.Credits = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Credits.setObjectName("Credits")
    self.menuDatei.addAction(self.openFile)
    self.menuDatei.addSeparator()
    self.menuDatei.addAction(self.saveFile)
    self.menuDatei.addAction(self.saveFileAs)
    self.menuHilfe.addAction(self.Credits)
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuDatei.menuAction())
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHilfe.menuAction())

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.menuDatei.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Datei"))
    self.menuHilfe.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Hilfe"))
    self.openFile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Öffnen"))
    self.actionSpeichern.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Speichern"))
    self.actionSpeichern_als.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Speichern als..."))
    self.saveFile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Speichern"))
    self.saveFileAs.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Speichern als..."))
    self.Credits.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Credits ©"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add layout to `MainWindow`. It seems to me that you're using QtDesigner. If so, then right click `MainWindow` in object browser, choose `Lay out` and select an appropriate layout. The horizontal or vertical will be ok to start with.

Or you may add layout in code. I hope this will work in Qt5:

```
self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
self.layout.addWidget(self.desk)
self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I´m using QtDesigner :)